# (Noob) Quick help on output statement

Tags: java

```
    if (gpa < 2.0)
    System.out.println("The student "  +first  +last + " is not graduating.");
```

This is my output statement. However the result I get is

The student BobPaul is not graduating.

How do I add a space between the +first and +last so that way my output statement looks like

The student Bob Paul is not graduating.

the correct answer is

System.out.println("The student "  +first + " " + last + " is not graduating.");

Comment: I'm sure you could have answered this question yourself, if you would have put a little though into it (it will make you a better programmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. Just concatenate a string " " with empty space in between.

```
System.out.println("The student "  +first + " " + last + " is not graduating.");
```

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer. I will flag it in when I am able to (12 minutes)